# Android WiFi protocol and Bluetooth Stack version wringer.

Tags: printing, bluetooth, stack, wifi, protocols

I am working on an app that will be printing to a Bluetooth and/or Wifi printer (device links below) from an Android device, and I was wondering if the Bluetooth stack and Wifi protocol in Android 2.2 is the same as 4.1-4.2, or if its been changed. Any related information will be helpful!

Thank you in advance.

[Brother Ruggedjet 4030](http://www.brother-usa.com/Mobile/ModelDetail.aspx?ProductID=RJ4030-K&PG=26) 
[Brother Ruggedjet 4040](http://www.brother-usa.com/Mobile/ModelDetail.aspx?ProductID=RJ4040-K&PG=26)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may see from the links below, Android's Bluez-based (http://www.bluez.org) bluetooth stack has been replaced in version 4.2 with Broadcom's stack (therefore starting from Android API17).

I don't know how this change will impact existing API's.

Links:

http://www.broadcom.com/press/release.php?id=s721534

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html